# ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

My imports :

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys
```

why am i getting that error while i'm clearly not importing tkinter and how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your imported packages requires tkinter as a dependency, so you need to install it.

```
# if you are using Anaconda
conda install tk

# if you are using Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: Collecting python3-tk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3-tk

Comment: I added directions for Ubuntu if you are using the standard Python3 in Ubuntu.